# Visual Studio Community 2015 - Simulator error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a big problem with VS simulator. When I try to run my app, I am getting this error

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to reinstal/repair VS installation but it didn't work. I've been searching for a week to find solution and failed. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you done what the error message says?

Comment: Yes.........................................